# what is the best approach to run many gulp watch tasks simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

**Is it better call multiple watchers or combine them into one?**

I have different tasks for different file types and currently I do this:

```
...

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch(paths.sass, batch(function (done) {
        gulp.start('sass');
        done();
    }));

    watch(paths.templates, batch(function (done) {
        gulp.start('templates');
        done();
    }));

    watch(paths.scripts, batch(function (done) {
        gulp.start('inject');
        done();
    }));
});

...
```

( the full gulpfile.js: https://gist.github.com/asfktz/2166e1b58c552f4db6cd )

It feels wrong right now and I thinks its better the have one watch stream and separate the stream into different streams, one for each task. 
am I right?